# Using a Python library to interact with adb and change to su on a device which doesn't have sudo

Tags: python, unix, adb, busybox, su

I'm currently using *pure-python-adb* to automate a few tasks using Python. The device I'm using is a Busybox based UNIX system, which has limited number of commands. It doesn't have `sudo`. The task I'm trying to accomplish is change the permission, owner and group of a new file that I have just pushed into the device. The problem right now is that in order to change the permission of a file, I should be in *su* mode. And to be in *su*, I have to give the password. This is where I'm stuck at. I'm unable to give the password to *su*.

This is what I have so far:

```
from ppadb.client import Client as AdbClient
client = AdbClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
device = client.device("device-6000")
device.shell("<command>")
```

I can pass normal commands like `ls -lh` or `cd <PATH>`, but I can't change to `su`. When I do pass `su`, the console just hangs. So I tried to pass the password along with the command using one of the answers I found online, `echo <PW> | su -s`, but the error I"m getting is,

> 'su: must be run from a terminal\r\n'

Is there any way to automate this task using Python?

Comment: You are using `pipe` in shell command. Check if `device.shell` supports pipe in command.

Comment: Even if I use, the normal adb shell, I can't do echo <PW> | su -s.

Comment: Try `su echo <PW>`

Comment: Says, no passwd entry for echo

Comment: Try enabling passwordless sudo access in /etc/passwd file.

Comment: Editing the passwd file is not option that we have.